# Storing data in Firebase-Database in hierarchy

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store the details of the User in the Firebase in this format:

```
User-Register
|
----1
    ---username:xyz
    ---phoneNo:9055505555
    ---password:abc
----2
    ---username.........
```

and so on.

I am writing this code on click of the registration button in application.
My java code is:

```
String getUsername = register_username.getText().toString();
        String getPhoneNo = register_phoneNo.getText().toString();
        String getPassword = register_password.getText().toString();

        userRegistrationInfo store_User_Details = new userRegistrationInfo(getUsername, getPhoneNo, getPassword);


        FirebaseDatabase databaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference_for_registration = databaseInstance.getReference("UserRegister");
        String childNumber=Integer.toString(count);
        reference_for_registration.child(childNumber).setValue(store_User_Details);
        count++;
```

My userRegistrationInfo class is:

```
public class userRegistrationInfo {

    String username;
    String phone_number;
    String password;



    public userRegistrationInfo()
    {

    }
    public userRegistrationInfo(String username,String phone_number,String password)

    {
        username=this.username;
        phone_number=this.phone_number;
        password=this.password;

    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPhone_number() {
        return phone_number;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

On running this code , I am not getting anything in the database. I am using the count for the id of the object which is created. But nothing is updated in the database for it.

How to reflect the changes in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Is better to get unique key for new user-register from firebase. Try to modify your code on click of the registration button in application.

```
    String getUsername = register_username.getText().toString();
    String getPhoneNo = register_phoneNo.getText().toString();
    String getPassword = register_password.getText().toString();

    userRegistrationInfo store_User_Details = new userRegistrationInfo(getUsername, getPhoneNo, getPassword);

    FirebaseDatabase databaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference_for_registration = databaseInstance.getReference();

    String key = reference_for_registration.child("UserRegister").push().getKey();

    Map<String, Object> store_User_DetailsValues = store_User_Details.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

    childUpdates.put("/UserRegister/" + key, store_User_DetailsValues);

    reference_for_registration.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

Add to userRegistrationInfo class

```
@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("username", username);
    result.put("phone_number", phone_number);
    result.put("password", password);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, just to clarify, in your code, you type `UserRegister` but in yout database format it stated as `User-Register`. Is that a typo or you might need check that one out.

Second, you need to clarify on the phone number attribute. The data in Firebase Database should be the same as property get function from your custom object (in this case, userRegistrationInfo class). So if your Firebase Database attribute listed as `phoneNo`, then your custom object should have `getPhoneNo` attribute to store the data. And vice versa.

And it is more common to use unique id auto-generated by Firebase. You can accomplish it by replacing your code with this:

`reference_for_registration.push().setValue(store_User_Details);`

Other than that, I think your code above should work fine. Try adding `.addOnCompleteListener` at the end of `setValue(store_User_Details)`. And from there, you can clarify more detail if something goes wrong.

Comment: getPhoneNo is a variable, not a function name.Please look into the code again.

Comment: yes in your code, getPhoneNo is a variable, but what I mean is something else. Before this become more confusing, let me ask you, do you prefer your database has `phone_number` or `phoneNo` ?

Comment: phone_number is what I prefer

Comment: then you need to rename `phoneNo` node in your Firebase Database to `phone_number` and try again, keep spirit